# Как не ловить отправляемые пакеты на RAW UDP "сервере"

Tags: c, сервер, udp, ethernet, echo

Столкнулся с следующей проблемой:

1. На заданном физическом  порту открываю сырой сокет (у меня это что-то типа eth0).
2. Обрабатываю данные из пакета нужным мне образом.
3. Отправляю обратно.

Всё работает, всё проверено, работает как надо, но создаёт много лишнего "шума".

Сама проблема/шум начинается в момент отправки. Отправил, и в тот же момент ловлю свой же пакет. Помимо этого принимающая сторона автоматически мне тоже шлёт какую-то фигню, от чего за считанные минуты лог файл в который я пишу принятое/отправленное оказывается  около 1 гб.

С формированием пакетов разобрался, с правильной задачей указания адресов - тоже. Но получилась адовая спам  машина. Как бы мне так извратиться, чтобы программа обрабатывала только уникальные пакеты, отбрасывая те, что я отправляю, и те, что приходят мне, как ответ на отправленное сообщение?

Comment: Например фильтрация по IP пакету

Comment: так  и сделал ` if(iph->daddr==dst_addr && iph->saddr==src_addr) {return;}
if(iph->daddr==src_addr && iph->saddr==dst_addr) {return;}`

Comment: почему не используешь обычные DGRAM сокеты?

Comment: извращенец я =))

Answer (score 1):

RAW пакеты фильтруются по BPF (через SO_ATTACH_FILTER). Это лучше чем каскал if потому как отрабатывает в ядре и отброшенный пакет не долетает до программы.

Cам асемблер bpf я компилировал через pcap_compile

```
struct bpf_program fp;
char filter_exp[] = "udp dst port 5555";
pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, 0)
```

`struct bpf_program` - это тоже самое что и `struct sock_fprog`

Comment: а можно по подробнее?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/oro350/8269805 пример  я нашёл, а вот что-то более подробное бы.

Comment: добавил как можно упростить себе жизнь с асемблером)

Comment: А что потом надо сделать с `fp`, чтобы фильтр в ядре заработал? (но все равно плюсую)

Comment: SO_ATTACH_FILTER потом

Comment: "Cам асемблер bpf я компилировал через pcap_compile" - вникаю как, но ответ реально дико полезный.

Comment: Это библиотека  от tcpdumpa. Пример как какраз в ответе. Человеческое заклинание в bpf программу переводит эта функция. Ручка от pcap тут не требуется, стоит null. SO_ATTACH_FILTER потом

Comment: @avp везде пишут что эта машинка в ядре работает. Её смысл в том чтоб в юзерспейс не гонять лишнее.

Comment: @eri спасибо огроменное, теперь вникну в https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html, чтоб нормально написать свои ограничения и  буду кайфовать. ( в такой простой штуке  я обязан сам разобраться))) )

Comment: @eri, ещё раз спасибо, справился с   правильным написанием  фильтра, есть там пара мелочей которые отлично расписаны https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html вот тут. осталась одна противная мелочь, скомпоновать строчку из  вводимых данных IP  и необходимых условий, вот тут я  не обойдусь без жопного количества каскадов IF. Но, если вдруг есть какие-то интересные идеи - буду рад совету.

Comment: там есть ingress egress - может поможет прочистить часть данных.